# Printing Pandas Columns With Unicode Characters

Tags: python, unicode, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a single column that contains a unicode encoded name.

```
import pandas as pd

no_unicode = pd.Series(['Steve', 'Jason', 'Jake'])
yes_unicode = pd.Series(['tea', 'caf\xe9', 'beer'])

var_names = dict(no_unicode = no_unicode, yes_unicode = yes_unicode)

df = pd.DataFrame(var_names)

print(df)
```

I can print the dataframe in ipython fine, but I get an error when I try to print the dataframe in Sublimetext (using py3).

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in
>   position 73: ordinal not in range(128)

I have searched high and low for a solution (and learned a lot about unicode in the process) but I cannot figure out how to print the dataframe while in Sublimetext.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very useful function `u` in `pandas.compat`, to make your values in unicode.:

```
In [26]:
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import u
no_unicode = pd.Series(['Steve', 'Jason', 'Jake'])
#yes_unicode = pd.Series(['tea', 'caf\xe9', 'beer'])
yes_unicode = pd.Series(map(u,['tea', 'caf\xe9', 'beer']))
var_names = dict(no_unicode = no_unicode, yes_unicode = yes_unicode)
df = pd.DataFrame(var_names)
print(df)

  no_unicode yes_unicode
0      Steve         tea
1      Jason        café
2       Jake        beer

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: I get an error with this code, "TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()"

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you are using `python 3.x`, change it to `list(map(......))` should do it, in `python 3` `map()` returns a `map object` rather than a `list`.